# How to pass matrix as a function parameter in the prototype?

Tags: c

I'm trying to pass a matrix as a parameter of a function, so as shown below, I wrote the function prototype, then when I try to call it, there is an error.

```
void init_a(int a[n][m], int row, int column);
void init_b(int b[m][p], int row, int column);

int main() {
    int n, m, p;
    printf("Enter n , m, p : ");
    scanf("%u %u %u",n,m,p);
    int a[n][m], b[m][p];

    init_a(a, n, m);
    init_b(b, m, p);

}

void init_a(int a[n][m],int n, int m) {
   ....
}

void init_b(int b[n][m],int m, int p) {
   ....
}
```

However I get an error that says undeclared variable.

```
75:19: error: ‘n’ undeclared here (not in a function)
 void init_a(int a[n][m],int row, int column){
                   ^
75:22: error: ‘m’ undeclared here (not in a function)
 void init_a(int a[n][m],int row, int column){
                      ^
```

and same for init_b.

Do I have to use a pointer in the function prototype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the compiler says, there are no variable `n`, `m` declared.

What you want to do is maybe:

```
void init_a(int row, int column, int a[][column]);
```

The size of the array should be passed *before* it is used as size in array notation.

Using pointer would be pretty tricky.

```
void print(int *arr, int m, int n)
```

You have to pass 2D array as single pointer, and accesing the variable via given index would be

```
*((arr+i*n) + j) // which is the same to arr[i][j]
```

And, the way to call the function would be

```
print((int *)a, m, n);
```

Passing double-pointer and trying to index will cause error, since the compiler doesn't know how much the size of row or column is. It't like "How much would I have to skip, when I go down to row?".

Comment: Thank you. Does it create an error if I do void init_a(nt row, int column, int a[row][column]);? or is there a reason to not put row?

Comment: It would not generate any problem, but  it's recommend not to do so. Doing so may make user to be inclined to false information, like "Oh, this function seems to accept only `row * column` matrix.", but the truth is, if the row or column is fixed, the other doesn't matter.